# making code block in css look good

Tags: css

I am trying to find the right css required to make my code block look good in my Jekyll powered Github Pages blog. I want it the code to look something like this (I'm using kramdown with syntax highlighting):

[image]

I tried highlight.js but I think my scss block is overwriting the formatting:

`pre {
    background-color: #D1D1D0;
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: 'Monaco', monospace;
    padding: 0 1em;
  }`

code {
    font-family: Monaco, monospace;
    font-size: $base-font-size;
    line-height: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 0.2em;
    letter-spacing: -0.05em;
    word-break: normal;
    /*border-radius: 5px;*/
  }

pre code {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    font-size: $base-font-size * 0.875;
    line-height: 1em;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-break: break-all;
  }

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The easiest way to do that, I think, is to simply include [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) in your page.

Check out [the Highlight.js demo](https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/) to see what style you want to use.
I guess that the Monokai theme would be the best match to that screenshot of yours.

Highlight.js does not require you to alter any markup because it (usually) works in automatic mode.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/styles/default.css"/>
<script src="/path/to/highlight.pack.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

After the insertion of the above code in the appropriate places, all your code blocks will be highlighted.

Provided that they are rendered like this:

```
<pre><code>
    // code here
</code></pre>
```

But that is the standard way of doing it, so I guess that the Jekyll thingie spits that out.

Having recommended that, I wonder if Jekyll doesn't ship with a highlighter of it's own? It probably does. Or not. ;)

Comment: Because it is hosted on Github, there already is syntax highlighting through kramdown. I am just trying to find the right color scheme basically using my pre {} blocks. I've edited my question with what I have currently.

Comment: Kramdown is a Markdown variant, not a syntax highlighter?

Comment: Sorry I have rouge set for the syntax highlighting. Don't I need to set a style for the highlighting though? Isn't this done in the scss like in my example?

Comment: Highlight.js adds all of that. You only have to adjust the code and pre tags if you want something 'special'. If you view the source for some highlighted code you will see that the library adds a lot of markup. You can modify how it looks by applying a style sheet (a theme) - there are tons on the highlight.js site.

Comment: I worked it out - my own style sheet was overriding some of the key aspects which highlight.js takes care of naturally. I have not setup highlight.js properly and can choose any theme I want. Thanks!